# An Exoplayer DASH Streaming example which always crashes when running on the phone

Tags: java, android-studio

> I used the following java code, and added the following permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file, but the video cannot be played when running on the phone, what is the problem?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.exo_player_view);

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayer"));
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://dash.akamaized.net/envivio/EnvivioDash3/manifest.mpd");
    DashMediaSource dashMediaSource = new DashMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory,
            new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory), null, null);

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));

    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

    exoPlayerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(dashMediaSource);
}
```

> permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

Comment: What is in stacktrace?

Comment: When l make the project，it is successful.However,when putting the app on the phone,the video couldn't be played.Can someone provide me a correct example of using ExoPlayer to play dash video? I am confused now, can someone provide me with the specific code and operation steps?

Comment: You can run your app in debug mode on the device, and take a look whats happening